# Angular dont show nested document

Tags: angular, api, nested, document

The angular is returning null for a field that contains a nested object, already checked by postman, everything is normal, also checked the database, only the angular can not show me this data

This is my api call

```
getVenda(): Promise<any>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            this._httpClient.get(environment.api_url+'/venda/' + this.routeParams.id)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    console.log(environment.api_url+'/venda/' + this.routeParams.id)
                    console.log(response)

                    this.Venda = response;
                    this.onVendaChanged.next(this.Venda);
                    resolve(response);
                }, reject);

        });
    }
```

this is the console return

```
cliente: {cpf: "01586606689", nome: "JOAO PAULO DA SILVA", id: "6"}
dataVenda: "2019-08-22T20:18:50.372Z"
entrada: 300
id: "30"
lojista: null
nParcelas: 4
obs: "tedasdsfasdf"
parcelas: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
primeiraParcela: "2019-09-21T20:18:50.374Z"
tipo: null
valor: 1000
__proto__: Object
```

the field "lojista" is coming null but should come an object
just like my call via postman

```
 "tipo": null,
    "valor": 1000,
    "parcelas": [
        {
            "tipo": "CARTAO",
            "fechada": null,
            "desconto": 0,
            "negativacao": null,
            "lote": null,
            "multa": 0,
            "jurosAutorizado": 0,
            "boleto": null,
            "renegociacao_id": null,
            "parcela": 0,
            "cobranca": null,
            "cpf": "01586606689",
            "id": "89",
            "descontoJuros": 0,
            "total_recebido": 0,
            "dataRecebimento": null,
            "dataUltimoVencimento": null,
            "pontoRecebimento": null,
            "juros": 0,
            "spc": null,
            "valor": 300,
            "baixa_user_id": null,
            "historico": null,
            "autenticacao": null,
            "pago": "S",
            "descricao": null,
            "descontoAutorizado": 0,
            "dataVencimento": "2019-08-22T20:19:03.410Z",
            "nfse": null,
            "resumo": null,
            "taxaJuros": 0,
            "dataUltimaVenda": null,
            "comissionada": null
        },
        {
            "tipo": "CARTAO",
            "fechada": null,
            "desconto": 0,
            "negativacao": null,
            "lote": null,
            "multa": 0,
            "jurosAutorizado": 0,
            "boleto": null,
            "renegociacao_id": null,
            "parcela": 1,
            "cobranca": null,
            "cpf": "01586606689",
            "id": "90",
            "descontoJuros": 0,
            "total_recebido": 0,
            "dataRecebimento": null,
            "dataUltimoVencimento": null,
            "pontoRecebimento": null,
            "juros": 0,
            "spc": null,
            "valor": 175,
            "baixa_user_id": null,
            "historico": null,
            "autenticacao": null,
            "pago": "N",
            "descricao": null,
            "descontoAutorizado": 0,
            "dataVencimento": "2019-09-21T20:18:50.374Z",
            "nfse": null,
            "resumo": null,
            "taxaJuros": 0,
            "dataUltimaVenda": null,
            "comissionada": null
        },
        {
            "tipo": "CARTAO",
            "fechada": null,
            "desconto": 0,
            "negativacao": null,
            "lote": null,
            "multa": 0,
            "jurosAutorizado": 0,
            "boleto": null,
            "renegociacao_id": null,
            "parcela": 2,
            "cobranca": null,
            "cpf": "01586606689",
            "id": "91",
            "descontoJuros": 0,
            "total_recebido": 0,
            "dataRecebimento": null,
            "dataUltimoVencimento": null,
            "pontoRecebimento": null,
            "juros": 0,
            "spc": null,
            "valor": 175,
            "baixa_user_id": null,
            "historico": null,
            "autenticacao": null,
            "pago": "N",
            "descricao": null,
            "descontoAutorizado": 0,
            "dataVencimento": "2019-10-21T20:18:50.374Z",
            "nfse": null,
            "resumo": null,
            "taxaJuros": 0,
            "dataUltimaVenda": null,
            "comissionada": null
        },
        {
            "tipo": "CARTAO",
            "fechada": null,
            "desconto": 0,
            "negativacao": null,
            "lote": null,
            "multa": 0,
            "jurosAutorizado": 0,
            "boleto": null,
            "renegociacao_id": null,
            "parcela": 3,
            "cobranca": null,
            "cpf": "01586606689",
            "id": "92",
            "descontoJuros": 0,
            "total_recebido": 0,
            "dataRecebimento": null,
            "dataUltimoVencimento": null,
            "pontoRecebimento": null,
            "juros": 0,
            "spc": null,
            "valor": 175,
            "baixa_user_id": null,
            "historico": null,
            "autenticacao": null,
            "pago": "N",
            "descricao": null,
            "descontoAutorizado": 0,
            "dataVencimento": "2019-11-20T19:18:50.374Z",
            "nfse": null,
            "resumo": null,
            "taxaJuros": 0,
            "dataUltimaVenda": null,
            "comissionada": null
        },
        {
            "tipo": "CARTAO",
            "fechada": null,
            "desconto": 0,
            "negativacao": null,
            "lote": null,
            "multa": 0,
            "jurosAutorizado": 0,
            "boleto": null,
            "renegociacao_id": null,
            "parcela": 4,
            "cobranca": null,
            "cpf": "01586606689",
            "id": "93",
            "descontoJuros": 0,
            "total_recebido": 0,
            "dataRecebimento": null,
            "dataUltimoVencimento": null,
            "pontoRecebimento": null,
            "juros": 0,
            "spc": null,
            "valor": 175,
            "baixa_user_id": null,
            "historico": null,
            "autenticacao": null,
            "pago": "N",
            "descricao": null,
            "descontoAutorizado": 0,
            "dataVencimento": "2019-12-20T19:18:50.374Z",
            "nfse": null,
            "resumo": null,
            "taxaJuros": 0,
            "dataUltimaVenda": null,
            "comissionada": null
        }
    ],
    "cliente": {
        "cpf": "01586606689",
        "nome": "JOAO PAULO DA SILVA",
        "id": "6"
    },
    "entrada": 300,
    "primeiraParcela": "2019-09-21T20:18:50.374Z",
    "dataVenda": "2019-08-22T20:18:50.372Z",
    "id": "30",
    "obs": "tedasdsfasdf",
    "nParcelas": 4,
    "lojista": {
        "razao": "EMPRESA TESTE",
        "cnpj": "67396351000134",
        "id": "2222"
    }
```

Comment: I could see a lot of issues with this code. You are mixing promises and observables. Also the API call should be there in service and in the component you need to subscribe.

Comment: Well, that doesn't justify why the Angular isn't displaying one of the nested objects.

Comment: If it's null, it's because it's null. Look at the raw JSON you get in the network panel of your browser dev tools.

Comment: I just arrived, the document is arriving correctly

Comment: I am getting crazy

Comment: if I give the console the object "console.log (response)" lojista is null, but if I use JSON.stringFy, I see the object perfectly

Comment: I don't know what happens with the angle but I made a "joke" that worked "JSON.parse (JSON.stringify (sale))"

Comment: thank you to everyone who tried to help me